# rails: how to render a popup just before action render :partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a print layout in haml for generating pdfs:

```
                = link_to I18n.t('eda.print'), {:controller => :persons, :action => :print}, :method => '', :remote => false
```

Is there a way to have a javascript popup for confirmation like "are you sure?" just before executing the print method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-javascript way:

```
= link_to I18n.t('eda.print'), {:controller => :persons, :action => :print}, 
:method => '', :remote => false, :data => {:confirm => 'Are you Sure ?' }
```

On clicking the link, it'll ask for user confirmation 'Are you Sure?' If you proceed further then respective controller -> action will be triggered.